# Error 500 with Basic Authorization and body content in Power Bi (API)

Tags: authentication, powerbi, basic-authentication, powerbi-desktop, http-status-code-500

I can't get a connection with login and password (Basic Authorization) for an API.

```
= let apiUrl = "(censored)",
body = Text.ToBinary("
{
    ""codEmitenteIni"": 000000,
    ""codEmitenteFin"": 999999,
    ""tipoRelatorio"": ""detalhado""
}
"),
result = Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl,[Headers=[#"Authorization"="Basic login:password"], Content=body]))
in
result
```

Error:

```
DataSource.Error: '*[...]*' (500) or return a HTML login page
```

I tried to change `"Authorization"` to `"Accept-Charset"` or `"Accept"` and it still does not work.

The request in postman it's working!
It's a totvs API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you encode `login` and `password`? In basic authentication, the value sent in the Authorization header should start with the `Basic`  part, then have a base64 url-encoded value of the string created by concatenating login, `:`, and password.

Postman does it automatically for you. Inspect the actual Authorization header that is sent in the Postman request. You should see something like `Basic bG9naW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=`.